# applWill a not-properly-closed DBConnection be finally closed after GC (after long time)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, garbage-collection, ado.net

I have legacy codes (VB6 Forms) that follow a bad design pattern. It connects to a database in constructor, and close it in the class's destructor (i.e., Class_Terminate for VB6).

There are hundreds of classes that follow this pattern (or use classes which follow this pattern).

We are now migrating it to .NET and met problem. Because when ADO is migrated to ADO.NET (this is a hard requirement), close ADO.NET connection in Finalize method will cause exception.

(More explanation: The exception is : InvalidOperationException: handle is not initialized. Watch into connection object, the State is still Open. From previous questions in StackOverflow, people's suggestion was to Open and Close the connection immediately after usage, and don't keep the connection open for the whole life-time of the class object.)

I've searched and found that in .NET, only unmanaged resources shall be released in Finalize. Object such as DBConnection shall not be closed in Finalize method.

This is a quite embarrassing situation. The best method for us currently is apparently not to Close each connection after usage, and reopen it before usage (it's some kind of time-consuming). We are actually considering to ignore the exception during Close in Finalize method.

I would like to ask,

1) Does DBConnection in ADO.Net implements a Finalize and will close the real underlying connection during GC? If this is true, then ignore close exception in Finalize) won't really do harm to us.

2) If not, will the underlying connections (maybe from connection pool?) be finally returned back to system or connection pool? Say the system or connection pool will check abnormal connection states and retrieve back the resources after some long time?

Thanks.

Comment: What exception you are getting? If you leave the connection open, the connection pool might get exhausted and no more connection available before the GC executes and that could lead your application in bad state. Why can not you create and open the connection when needed and close and dispose it as soon you are done with it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The exception is "InvalidOperationException: Handle is not initialized". And the Connection state is still OPEN. I've searched this exception and a lot of ppl have asked similar questions, but all suggestion was to Open / Use / Close in each method and don't keep the connection and close it in Finalize.

Comment: If you will not the connection then it will not get closed automatically and connection pooling depends on your setting in the web config. If you use the pooling then it will retrieve the active connections and use them.

Comment: I know it's not your question, but if you know the current pattern is bad in the VB app, and you're doing a migration to a C# app, why not do it the recommended way?

Comment: @Gaurav It is not web server, it is just a normal Windows form application, which has very complicated logic. Frankly it has hundreds of classes and each is in .DLL form and link to each other. Knowing when shall each DBConnection be closed is a quite headache problem.

Comment: @Ben It's all about money of course. :p Frankly it has hundreds of classes and each is in .DLL form and link to each other. Knowing when shall each DBConnection be closed is a quite headache problem.

Comment: Not sure if you have read [This](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/693328-dbconnection) but replies in the thread explains why you should not be closing connection in Destructor/finalizer. It suggest to have class implemented from IDisposable if it uses DbConnection so that conn.Close can be called in Dispose method. If you have database connection state known across various layers of the application then I think you need to start thinking abut re-layering and make them independent. Your company will be spending more money managing bad layered application than correcting it right now....

Comment: Apparently there is no data access layer. I predict that as soon as you finished this upgrade a new requirement will be presented telling you that you will be switching to a different database back-end.

Comment: You're hemming yourself in in more ways than one if you try to "fix" or "tweak" this design rather than fixing it properly. These long-lived connections mean effectively that all use of these classes has to be serialized/single threaded. Which means you're cutting yourself off from all kinds of opportunities as/when you seek to employ parallelism or asynchrony. Single threaded access was the norm/assumed in VB6 but is abnormal in this day and age in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Does DBConnection in ADO.Net implements a Finalize and will close the real underlying connection during GC? If this is true, then ignore close exception in Finalize) won't really do harm to us.
>
> 2) If not, will the underlying connections (maybe from connection pool?) be finally returned back to system or connection pool? Say the system or connection pool will check abnormal connection states and retrieve back the resources after some long time?

1. The garbage collector will collect only managed code. This is why we have the `IDisposable` interface.
   The underlying connection is not managed code, and therefor will not be closed by the garbage collector.
2. The connection pool will close the underlying connection after x time it's closed and not used. A "real" connection to the database that is tied to an open instance of  `IDbConnection` will not be available for the connection pool to give out or to close.

Combine these two facts together and you'll soon understand that keeping an open connection on the class level will not only prevent it from being collected by the garbage collector as long you have an active reference to that class, but also prevent the connection pool to kill the underlying connection.
This leads to a number of problems already mentioned in the comments.

I understand you have a lot of classes connecting to the database like this (BTW, even back in the days of VB6 and ADO it was a bad practice) - so changing each class manually is not feasible.

However, you can create your own classes to add a layer between the application code and the ADO.Net code, and instead of mapping ADO directly to ADO.Net, map it to your own class.

So basically you'll have a Connection class that implements the IDbConnection interface and a Command class that implements the IDbCommand interface.

In your IDbCommand implementation you should open and close the actual connection when executing the command methods.

This way, you have a relatively small amount of work mapping the old code to the new code, and all the benefits of only using the connection when you actually need it.